# Air SecureSocket for iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, ssl, air, adobe

I am developing an Adobe Air application that will run on an iPad and am looking for a way to send secure data through a socket.

The Adobe APIs show the SecureSocket class but it is not available for the mobile platform. Does anyone know of a native extension that would allow for this or any other method to send secure data through a socket on the mobile platform?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use HTTPS?

Comment: HTTPS can't be used as the app has been setup for actual Sockets. Socket connection also needs to be open as data is pushed from the server to the client (streaming).

Any other ideas?